# Help with URL structure

Tags: seo, url, alias

I have a site with 3 category levels in some areas, 2 category levels on another areas and only one category level in other areas prior to the content. I am trying to settle in on the most consistent URL patterns. From what i have read shorter is better, so i am hesitant to show all three categories as my content titles are multi-word as well as my categories.

So if I were to shorten this:

domain.com/clothes/pants/jeans/Levi-skinny-jeans

Is it better to keep the functional URL from the parent category, and go to content skipping the 2 sub categories?

domain.com/clothes/Levi-skinny-jeans

Or would it be better to keep the immediate context though the URL doesn't represent the path properly?:

domain.com/jeans/Levi-skinny-jeans

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's really just a matter of preference since search engines like Google won't rank one over the other - chose whichever one you think is more readable/recognizable by visitors. We get a lot of [opinion-based](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) questions like this seeking the _perfect_ URL structure so we mark those as a duplicate of the linked question which goes into some detail on the subject.

Comment: Thanks Dan! I saw that thread shortly after posting this.